# PHP on command line performance vs Ruby/Python/etc

Tags: php, performance, shell, codeigniter-2

I recently realised that there is a huge difference between calling your php cron scripts using wget vs calling them using the commandline

```
php index.php controller function
```

(using codeigniter here)

especially if the script is doing a lot of processing in the backend.

What I realised is if apache is removed from the picture, php behaves just like any other scripting language you would use on the command line.

My question is, are all the scripting languages on the commandline on an equal footing when they work on the command line in terms of performance(lets say, if we're building a web-crawler) or are there major flaws or performance drawbacks with using php, as opposed to something like Ruby, Python or Perl.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Scripting languages all have different performance levels. Sometimes the difference is quite significant. You can find several performance comparisons under various conditions, such as [ScriptPerf](http://dj1.willowmail.com/~jeske/Projects/ScriptPerf/) and [here](http://onlyjob.blogspot.com/2011/03/perl5-python-ruby-php-c-c-lua-tcl.html).

If you're doing a web crawler, though, the time spent in script execution may be overcome by the time waiting for web responses. The best way to really check the performance difference is to run a few tests representative of your application and measure. It will depend upon how much really is "a lot of processing" in the background. But if that background processing really is quite significant versus the web response times, then the various online benchmarks would give a reasonable, first order answer.